# how to supress "protocol handler" pop up for anonymous\incognito chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running an automation on mac and on ubunto (using cucumber, selenium web driver, junit)

during the automation I click a link with non http protocol

an "External protocol request" popup appears.

[image]

It blocks my test from testing the rest of the webpage.

How can disable this popup for all chrome profiles? even incognito\anonymous chrome?

I have tried to add "" to the `/Users/eladb/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Local State` file.

`protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{.."waze":false,"mailto":false,..}`

and also tried:

`protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{.."waze":ture,"mailto":false,..}`

but even after a restart and running the test, the popup appears.

Comment: Please see this [link](http://thetechjournal.com/how-to/tutorial-how-to-re-authorize-opening-of-external-applications-from-google-chrome.xhtml) belongs to Windows  but I hope still useful

Answer (score 0):

Create you driver instance with chrome options as follows:

```
ChromeOptions cChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();   
cChromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
WebDriver _driver=new ChromeDriver("path_to_your_Chrom_Driver", cChromeOptions);
```

Comment: can you please explain what's `"--test-type"` ?

Comment: https://support.saucelabs.com/entries/52471990-How-to-hide-the-warning-message-in-Chrome-35-

Comment: it didn't help. still shows "External protocol request" popup

Answer (score 0):

I tried the 'Local State' file also not working.  Someone pointed out the folder Default/Preferences file.  Make your change there and it will work.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit what changes you made to the Default/Preferences file?